# Command Prompt: Running multiple commands in parallel

Tags: django, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file which runs different commands in the command prompt. I want to run each command in parallel and I know that it can be done by using the START command. However after sometime, I want to send command to some of the command prompts windows which I have opened already. Is there a way to do it?

This is the thing I am working on.
I have 5 different django projects that I have to execute through a script file
I used Start command to execute them in parallel and managed to get them running in different command prompt windows. Then I have to do some tasks on each django server.

After that, I have to close all the five servers that were running. I also want to access the 5 open command prompts again and close the windows instead of manually closing each of them. 
How do I get to do that.

This is the code I have so far:

## script1.bat

> > cd F:\app1
> >
> > > start c:\Python27\python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8180
> >
> > cd F:\app2
> >
> > > start c:\Python27\python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8200

When I run this it starts running the servers in two different windows. But when the tasks are finished, I want to go back to the window and disconnect the servers and close the windows.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your example is contrived and is of no use - it doesn't explain the task.  If you want an actual answer to a problem then you have to describe the actual problem.

Comment: Okay. Now I have updated it with the actual problem.

Comment: Are the python windows interactive?  Do you need to enter commands after starting each server?  The task is still a little unclear.

Comment: Yes the python windows are interactive and I have to run a few commands. The problem is that I don't know how to send those commands to the same command prompt window that was opened before. Is there some way to give a name to each window and execute the desired commands in that window?

Comment: You can create separate batch files on-the-fly to launch each task - I don't use python but a problem might be: how do you get input into a python window?  `Sendkeys` using VBS can work if the keyboard is not in use when this is launched.

Comment: How do I make batch files on-the-fly?

Answer (score 0):

just `start` secondary batch scripts which do all you want sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to create on-the-fly batch files and launch them using start

Getting the input into the python windows is the next task.

```
@echo off
del "%temp%\manage.py.*.bat" 2>nul    
:loop1
set "file1=%temp%\manage.py.%random%.bat"
if exist "%file1%" goto :loop1
(
   echo cd /d "F:\app1"
   echo c:\Python27\python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8180
   echo exit
)>"%file1%"

:loop2
set "file2=%temp%\manage.py.%random%.bat"
if exist "%file2%" goto :loop2
(
   echo cd /d "F:\app2"
   echo c:\Python27\python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8200
   echo exit
)>"%file2%"

for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do call start ""  "%%file%%a%%"
```